# Simple math task: 2 numbers given, we have to find the third. I just need a formula for it

Tags: algorithm, math

I need a formula for counting the number of combinations within a given limit of numbers. There must only be 2 numbers given, we have to find the third.

For example, for **2**(number of repetitions) and **3**(limit number), the result would be **3**, because there are 3 combinations for the digits: **1 and 2, 1 and 3, 2 and 3**. 
For **2** and **4** the result is **6**,
For **3** and **5** the result is **10**,
For **6** and **7** the result is **7**, etc.

The first number has to be smaller than the second.

A formula is needed for figuring out the result, if the first number is **A**, the second is **B**, what would **C** is going to be?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming but rather belongs on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) once the questioner has added more of his own work and explained just where he is stuck.

Comment: I didn't know about it

Comment: All Stack Exchange communities have guidelines to cover what is homework, have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). The formula is going to be `C = B! / (A!*(B-A)!)` (where `!` is the factorial operation). It's also worth noting that the first number can be equal to the second -- there should only be one repetition in that case. By convention `0! == 1` and it is OK where both numbers are equal because `C(n, n) = 1` and this means `n!/(n! * 0!)`.

Unfortunately, since factorial grows *very* quickly (`21!` is too large for a 64-bit unsigned integer), you probably can't compute this directly. Wikipedia has a few algorithms you can use [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Computing_the_value_of_binomial_coefficients).

Comment: Thank you very much, Helium_1s2!

Comment: Sorry for posting here, I didn't know about special mathematics forums for that kind of questions